# POST API returns null values from retrofit but works in postman

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am a bit new to retrofit and android, so I am really embarrassed

See below error I get from Retrofit when I try to consume an API with the structure below

### The Error

```
  D/LOGIN: onResponse: >> UserOutputObj{response='null', response_text='null', user=null, status=null, response_Code=0, message='null', msg='null', token='null', zero=0}
```

Please advice me on the way to consume the API without getting the above error.

See my code below

### Retrofit client instance

```
public static Retrofit getLogInRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(LOG_IN_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

### Login Data Service

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface GetLogInDataService {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<UserOutputObj> getServiceData(@Body LoginInputObj input);
}
```

### actual implementation

```
   //retrofit starts ===
                GetLogInDataService service = RetrofitClientInstance.getLogInRetrofitInstance().create(GetLogInDataService.class);
                Call<OutputObj> call = service.getServiceData(myLoginInp);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<OutputObj>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<OutputObj> call, Response<OutputObj> response) {
                        OutputObj finalOutput = response.body();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: >> "+ response.body().toString());
                        assert finalOutput != null;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: finalOutput >>" + finalOutput.toString());
                        UserInfo user = finalOutput.getUser();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: user:" + user);

                        if (user != null) {
                            Login_Token = finalOutput.getToken();
                            Login_Message = finalOutput.getMessage();
                            Login_status = finalOutput.getStatus();                 if (Login_status) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: status is Successful");
                                type = user.getType();
                                name = user.getFullname();
                                dob = user.getDob();
                                city = user.getCity();
                                email = user.getEmail();
                                id = String.valueOf(user.getId());
                                gender = user.getGender();
                                rating = user.getRating();
                                Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Login_Token: " + Login_Token);
    
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: status is false");
                            }
    
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: VERIFY: " + Login_status);
                        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Login_Message: " + Login_Message);
                        server_check = true;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserOutputObj> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: INSIDE: onFailure");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: AN ERROR OCCURRED");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: Cause " + t.getCause());
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: getMessage " + t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

### log output

```
D/LOGIN: onResponse: >> UserOutputObj{response='null', response_text='null', user=null, status=null, response_Code=0, message='null', msg='null', token='null', zero=0}
```

D/LOGIN: onResponse: finalOutput >>UserOutputObj{response='null', response_text='null', user=null, status=null, response_Code=0, message='null', msg='null', token='null', zero=0}

I expect to get either the below JSON FAILURE RESPONSE or JSON SUCCESS RESPONSE and not the null responses i keep geting

### JSON FAILURE RESPONSE

```
{
    "OutputObject": {
        "response": "0",
        "status": false,
        "response_text": "user does not exists",
        "message": "Number Not exist",
        "response_Code": 400
    }
}
```

### JSON SUCCESS RESPONSE

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": true,
        "message": "Login Succesful",
        "token": "160444ef2fe0321-12P28071e2d6934764",
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2020-11-03T19:40:34.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-03T19:40:34.000000Z",
            "fullname": "Mr Guy 4",
            "email": "mekefesassfeghe@gmail.com",
            "email_verified_at": "2020-11-03T21:52:01.941539Z",
            "type": "Customer",
            "father_name": null,
            "gender": "male",
            "dob": "1983/01/26",
            "number": "19077834474589",
            "city": "Yosemeni Park",
            "state": "Las Vegas",
            "country": "United States",
            "address": "No 500 Correct address street",
            "status": "",
            "rating": 0,
            "token_id": "",
            "reg_date": "2020-11-03 19:40:34"
        },
        "response_Code": 200
    }
}
```

### serialized object

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OutputObj implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String response;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String response_text;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private UserInfo user;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Boolean status;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int response_Code;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String message;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String msg;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String token;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int zero;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OutputObj{" +
                "response='" + response + '\'' +
                ", response_text='" + response_text + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", response_Code=" + response_Code +
                ", message='" + message + '\'' +
                ", msg='" + msg + '\'' +
                ", token='" + token + '\'' +
                ", zero=" + zero +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The API works perfectly when invoked using Postman but returns null values from the Apps using retrofit
Please advise me on the way to consume the API as I have been cracking my head over this for a week

Answer (score 0):

I guess retrofit does not like single slashes
I needed to change the base URL to something without the slash